# Rudin's functional analysis, section 3.22 (Extreme points)

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, definition

I struggle to understand the definition of "Extreme set" and "Extreme point".

> Let $K$ a subset of a vector space $X$. A non-empty set $S \subset K$ is called an extreme set of $K$ if no point of $S$ is an internal point of any line whose whose end points are in $K$, except when both points are in $S$. Analytically, the condition can be expressed as follows: if $x, y \in K \;,\; 0 < t < 1$ and
>   $$
> (1-t)x + ty \in S
> $$
>   then $x \in S$ and $y \in S$.

Can anyone explain how does the analytical condition follow from the definition? For some reason it seems to me the definition itself is a bit twisted.

Also we have

> The *extreme points* of $K$ are the extreme sets that consist of just one point. The set of all extreme points of $K$ will be denoted by $E(K)$.

What's an example set consisting of just a single point that isn't an extreme set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The analytical description is just the parametrization of a line. For example, the line between $(1,1)$ and $(2,2)$ is given by $\{t(1,1)+(1-t)(2,2):t\in[0,1]\}$, Note that $t(1,1)+(1-t)(2,2)=(2-t,2-t)$ which indeed is the line between (1,1) and (2,2).

Now to understand the notion of extremeness it is important to understand extreme sets are extreme with regard to some other set $K$. Let's consider the square $K$ with corner point (0,0), (1,0), (1,1) and (0,1). The extreme points of the square are exactly the corner points (0,0), (1,0), (1,1) and (0,1). Extreme sets of $K$ are of course the extreme points and the extreme point sets, $K$ itself and the edges of $K$. (And unions of these sets.)

To proof this you can use the analytical definition of extreme sets. Take for example the edge between (1,0) and (1,1), this is the set $\{(1,\lambda):\lambda\in[0,1]\}$. Now let $x,y\in K$ such that there is some $t\in(0,1)$ such that $tx+(1-t)y=(1,\lambda)$ for some  $\lambda\in[0,1]$. First of all note that $x=(x_{1},x_{2})$ and $y=(y_{1},y_{2})$ with $x_{1},x_{2},y_{1},y_{2}\in[0,1]$. We find 
$$tx+(1-t)y=(tx_{1}+(1-t)y_{1},tx_{2}+(1-t)y_{2})=(1,\lambda).$$
So $1=tx_{1}+(1-t)y_{1}\leq t+t-1=1$ which implies that $x_{1}=y_{1}=1$ and thus $x,y\in\{(1,\lambda):\lambda\in[0,1]\}$ which therefore is an extreme set.

I hope this helped.

Comment: I get, of course, that the analytical description represents a line. What I don't get is how that expression follows from the definition. Also... the analytical description isn't a line but it's more a condition involving a line.

Comment: The word definition is also a condition involving a line, so I'm not entirely certain where the disconnect is for you.

Comment: Maybe a picture of what an extreme set is a what isn't might help. So I can get a feeling.

Comment: Sorry but in your example with the square why aren't the edges also extreme sets?

Comment: Edges are extreme sets as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: But no point in the edge (apart from the corners) is an extreme point, right?

Comment: As far as pictures go I don't really know how to add those, but let's consider two non-extreme sets: First of all $\{(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})\}$, the midpoint of the square. We can see that $\frac{1}{2}(0,0)+\frac{1}{2}(1,1)=(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$. As $(0,0)\not\in\{(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})\}$ and $(1,1)\not\in\{(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})\}$, $\{(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})\}$ is not an extreme set. Another example is $C=\{(1,s):s\in(\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4})\}$, again $\frac{1}{2}(1,0)+\frac{1}{2}(1,1)=(1,\frac{1}{2})\in C$, while $(0,0)\not\in C$ and $(1,1)\not\in C$.

Comment: Yes, no point in the edge, except for the corners are extreme points.

Comment: I think I got it, don't worry. Basically given $K$ and $S \subset K$, $S$ is an extreme set if we can "cross" such set with a line whose endpoints are in $K - S$ (complement of $S$ w.r.t. $K$), can you confirm?

Comment: That's exactly right.

Comment: Very last question... is the empty set also an extreme set in $K$?

Comment: By definition it's not. (See your own post.)